# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' controllers/profile.php on line 7

Tags: php

I have an error in my profile.php but i dont understand why ?.

When i browse on my website in localhost , i have no error but when i upload it on my server and try to go on the url i have this error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in httpd.www/mst/controllers/profile.php on line 7

My code line :

```
$post_data = params('current_member');
$post_data['signup_nom'] = params('current_member')['lastname'];
```

I dont understand this error, anyone can help me ?

Thank's

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? `array dereferencing` was introduced in 5.4

Comment: Your localhost version is different from your server version. That's why it worked in localhost but is giving trouble at server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your PHP version does not support `params('current_member')['lastname'];` syntax.

Just try with:

```
$post_data = params('current_member');
$post_data['signup_nom'] = $post_data['lastname'];
```

Comment: How i can take the id of my current_member ? 

$post_data['id'] doesnt work.